# When pressing the signup button the register form re-renders for a split second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, crud

[image: Routes.js][image]I have a register page I am building and when you submit the form the form rerenders for just a split second at the bottom of the screen before taking you to the next step in the signup process. I have rewritten it several times and it keeps happening. I am at a loss as to why this problem keeps reoccuring.

Thank You in advance for all the help everyone provides. Hope you all have a great day and happy coding!

```
//Signup.jsx
            import React, { Component } from 'react'
            import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
            import axios from 'axios'
            // import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
            import { signUpThroughFirebase } from '../../firebase/firebase.utils.js'
            import './Signup.scss'
            import passwordReveal from '../../assets/eye-solid.svg'
            import google from '../../assets/google.svg';
            import facebook from '../../assets/facebook.svg';
            import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/UserContext.js'

            // check to see if email is valid
            const validEmailRegex = RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i);

            const validateForm = errors => {
                let valid = true;
                // check to see if any errors exist, otherwise form is invalid
                Object.values(errors).forEach(error => {
                    error.length > 0 && (valid = false)
                });
                return valid;
            }

            export default class Signup extends Component {
                state = {
                    credentials: {
                        id: '',
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                        passwordCheck: '',
                        tosCheck: false
                    },
                    errors: {
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                        passwordCheck: '',
                        tosCheck: ''
                    },
                    passwordReveal: false,
                    passwordConfirmReveal: false
                }

                toggleReveal = (e, which) => {
                    if(which) this.setState({...this.state, passwordConfirmReveal: !this.state.passwordConfirmReveal});
                    else this.setState({ ...this.state, passwordReveal: !this.state.passwordReveal});
                }

                handleChange = e => {
                    let { name, value, checked } = e.target;
                    let errors = this.state.errors;

                    // handle input validation here
                    switch(name) {
                        case 'email' :
                            if (!value.length) errors.email = 'email is a required field';
                            else if (validEmailRegex.test(value) === false) errors.email = 'email must be a valid email';
                            else errors.email = '';
                            break;
                        case 'password' :
                            if (!value.length) errors.password = 'password is a required field';
                            else if (value.length < 8) errors.password = 'password must be at least 8 characters';
                            else errors.password = '';
                            break;
                        case 'passwordCheck' :
                            if (this.state.credentials.password !== value) errors.passwordCheck = 'passwords do not match';
                            else errors.passwordCheck = '';
                            break;
                        case 'tosCheck' :
                            if (!checked) {
                                value = false;
                                errors.tosCheck = 'terms and conditions must be accepted to continue';
                            } else {
                                value = true;
                                errors.tosCheck = '';
                            };
                            break;
                        default :
                            break;
                    }

                    this.setState({
                        errors,
                        credentials: {
                            ...this.state.credentials,
                            [name]: value
                        }
                    })
                    // console.log(this.state.credentials)
                }

                onSubmit = e => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    const { email, password, passwordCheck, tosCheck } = this.state.credentials
                    const user = { email: this.state.credentials.email, password: this.state.credentials.password }
                    //if no error exists, make the request to the backend
                    if (email && password && passwordCheck && tosCheck && validateForm(this.state.errors)) {
                        axios
                        .post('https://infinite-meadow-87721.herokuapp.com/auth/register', user)
                        .then(res => {
                            this.setState({
                                ...this.state,
                                credentials: {
                                    ...this.state.credentials,
                                    id: res.data._id 
                                }
                            })
                            this.props.history.push('/account')
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err))
                    } else {
                        console.log('x')
                    }
                }

                render() {
                    return (
                        <UserContext.Consumer>
                            {props => {
                                if(this.state.credentials.id !== '') {
                                    props.setLoggedInUser(this.state.credentials); 
                                }
                                // console.log(props);

                                return (
                                <div className='sign-up-page-container'>
                                    <h1 className='sign-up-header'>SIGN UP</h1>

                                    <div className='sign-up-forms'>
                                        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className='sign-up-email' noValidate>
                                            <label className='form-input-label'>
                                                EMAIL
                                                <input
                                                    type='email'
                                                    name='email'
                                                    // placeholder='E-mail'
                                                    value={this.state.credentials.email}
                                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                    className='form-input'
                                                    required
                                                />
                                            </label>
                                            <p className='form-input-error'>{this.state.errors.email}</p>

                                            <label className='form-input-label'>
                                                PASSWORD

                                                <div className='password-container'>
                                                    <input
                                                        type={this.state.passwordReveal ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                                        name='password'
                                                        // placeholder='Password'
                                                        value={this.state.credentials.password}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        required
                                                        className='form-input'
                                                    />
                                                    <img className='password-toggle' src={passwordReveal} alt='toggle password' onClick={(e) => this.toggleReveal(e, 0)} />
                                                </div>
                                            </label>
                                            <p className='form-input-error'>{this.state.errors.password}</p>

                                            <label className='form-input-label'>
                                                CONFIRM PASSWORD
                                                <div className='password-container'>
                                                    <input
                                                        type={this.state.passwordConfirmReveal ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                                        name='passwordCheck'
                                                        // placeholder='Retype password'
                                                        value={this.state.credentials.passwordCheck}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        required
                                                        className='form-input'
                                                    />
                                                    <img className='password-toggle' src={passwordReveal} alt='toggle password' onClick={(e) => this.toggleReveal(e, 1)} />
                                                </div>
                                            </label>
                                            <p className='form-input-error'>{this.state.errors.passwordCheck}</p>

                                            <div className='tos'>
                                                <input type='checkbox' name='tosCheck' id='tosCheck' value={this.state.credentials.tosCheck} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                                <label for='tosCheck' className='tos-text'>I agree to the <a href='google.com' className='tos-text-link'>Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <p className='form-input-error'>{this.state.errors.tosCheck}</p>

                                            <button
                                                className='sign-up-button'
                                                type='submit'
                                                name='signup_submit'
                                            >
                                                SIGN UP
                                            </button>

                                            <div className='sign-up-automatic mobile'>
                                                <div className='firebase-buttons mobile'>
                                                    <button onClick={() => signUpThroughFirebase('google', this.props.history)} className='social-sign-in google'>
                                                        <img className='button-img' src={google} alt='sign up with google' /> SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE
                                                    </button>

                                                    <button onClick={() => signUpThroughFirebase('facebook', this.props.history)} className='social-sign-in facebook'>
                                                        <img className='button-img' src={facebook} alt='sign up with facebook' /> SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <Link to='/Signin' className='sign-in-redirect'>I already have an account</Link>
                                        </form>

                                        <h2 className='sign-up-or'>OR</h2>

                                        <div className='sign-up-automatic'>
                                            <div className='firebase-buttons'>
                                                <button onClick={() => signUpThroughFirebase('google', this.props.history)} className='social-sign-in google'>
                                                    <img className='button-img' src={google} alt='sign up with google' /> SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE
                                                </button>

                                                <button onClick={() => signUpThroughFirebase('facebook', this.props.history)} className='social-sign-in facebook'>
                                                    <img className='button-img' src={facebook} alt='sign up with facebook' /> SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    )
                                }}

                            </UserContext.Consumer>
                        )
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this bit more `when you submit the form the form rerenders for just a split second at the bottom of the screen before taking you to the next step`?

Comment: Hard to explain  accurately I have a gif of it but I see no way to post it here. When you submit you can see at the bottom of the screen, just before it goes to the next step, the the main h1 that says signup here.

Comment: you can add images in description

Answer (score 0):

It was the Transition Group that was causing the problem. Commented out that and it stopped doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setState` this way:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {...state, other: 'prarams'};
});
```

Instead of using `...this.state` because it is async, and `this.state` could have been changed.